# Can i move local maven repository to internal repository when i set the internal repo for the first time?

Tags: maven, artifactory

i wanted to setup artifactory as internal repo after i had actually used maven and populated my local repository during various builds. Before I set up artifactory on my machine, my local repository has already downloaded various libraries on to my local machine under .m2. Now I am setting up internal repo using Artifactory. Is there a quick way to move my local repository under .m2 to artifactory so that i don't have to again download all the libraries to get my artifactory up with the required libs.

Currently what i have to do is remove all folders under local repo (.m2\repository) and then allow my maven build to download on to artifactory. I am looking for a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: You can also follow steps in maven documentation http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id>    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>

Answer (score 8):

You've got a number of options:

- Assuming that you would like to push all artifacts into one repository and keep the same folder structure as in your file-system, Artifactory's got a number of [good import utilities](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-RepositoriesImportandExport) in its administration UI at:

> *Admin->Import & Export->Repositories->Import Repository from Path*.

- For more flexibility, you can write a simple script that iterates over the .m2 folder and sends an HTTP PUT command for every artifact and thus be able to customize the paths and target repositories, for example:
  `curl -X PUT -u username:password -T path/to/file.jar "http://myhost:8080/artifactory/my-target-repo/path/to/file.jar"`